# Outlook VSTO Plugins - can we add an additional option in outlook "To-DO" bar and load Winform/HTML form on click of it?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am looking for any solution to add an additional menu item under outlook "To-DO" bar in the explorer view and on click of it load winform/html form in the custom task panel. The way we can do with individual email / meeting items.

If we choose that new option like "Calendar", "People" or "Task", it should by default open with the form we want to load.

"To-DO" bar seems to be very useful and convenient similar way if we can add our custom form then would be very useful.

Please refer below image for more information about "To-Do" bar I  am talking about.
[image: Outlook TO-DO Bar Explorer View]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `startfromscratch` attribute of your ribbon markup if you want to extend the built-in controls. If you set the Ribbon element's `startFromScratch` attribute to `true`, the Ribbon hides all of its content (so you do not have to do the work to hide everything manually). When you set the `startFromScratch` attribute to `true`, it makes the following changes:

- Hides all the existing Ribbon tabs, including the Add-Ins tab
- Modifies the Microsoft Office menu to include only the New, Open, Save, Application Options, and Exit commands

Read more about the Fluent UI in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thanks how about displaying form in custom task panel ? If that is feasible then only it's worth to explore ribbon part!

Comment: Yes, it is. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/stephen_griffin/adjacent-windows-in-outlook .

Comment: Thanks! looks like that Adjacent window page has been removed and it's not supported. Is there any other reference?

Comment: This technology is not officially supported. You may consider using `Advanced Outlook form regions` as well, see https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions-basics.php

Comment: Thank you! Form regions are something again to go back with outlook forms, I would prefer to have html forms the way we can do with custom task pane. Looks like this is easy with web based add in but not supported for VSTO based? pasting url of web based add-in in my next comment.

Comment: web based add in - https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lawsitesblog.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F509%2F2016%2F04%2FLawToolBox365-1024x548.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lawsitesblog.com%2F2016%2F04%2Flawtoolbox-readies-launch-office-365-add-outlook.html&tbnid=YPLnUSw99NNeTM&vet=12ahUKEwihlqa0wdHqAhULOBQKHTgmB1EQMyhbegQIARB7..i&docid=eEoTkgpp92WX1M&w=1024&h=548&q=outlook%20365%20add%20in&ved=2ahUKEwihlqa0wdHqAhULOBQKHTgmB1EQMyhbegQIARB7

Comment: You need to develop a web-based add-in then. See [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator).